# How to find a solution of a large system of linear diophantine inequalities?

Tags: linear-algebra, convex-optimization, computer-algebra, sage

I need to find a solution (all solutions, or at least upper and lower bounds) in positive integer numbers to the system $Ax \ge f$, where $A$ is an integer matrix.

With SageMath, I solved it with the function

```
Polyhedron.integral_points()
```

But, this is very slow and can take about 2-3 hours for a matrix which is about $30 \times 10$.

Is there another, faster way to do this? Preferably with SageMath or Python.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Essentially this is an integer linear programming problem (e.g. for finding bounds on a variable, your objective could be to maximize or minimize that variable).  Although integer linear programming is NP-complete, there is well-developed software for this which should be quite fast for a problem the size you mentioned. In SageMath you can use the MILP class.

Answer (score 2):

I suggest to employ [Normaliz backend](https://doc.sagemath.org/html/en/reference/discrete_geometry/sage/geometry/polyhedron/backend_normaliz.html) in SageMath, which is very efficient. Also, if there are infinitely many solutions, it's worth to compute `integral_points_generators()` rather than `integral_points()` -- the latter is limited to 10,000 points by default.